# How to leverage discriminated union to infer return type of a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics, union

Given the following types, interfaces, and getData function below I'm trying to find a way to leverage discriminated unions so that the TS compiler can narrow the return type of `getData(source: DOSources)` to the associated `DOTypes`

```
// Expected behavior
const result = getData("dataObjectA");

// result.data should be a string but in this case the TS compiler will complain 
// that data does not have the toLowerCase() function
result.data.toLowerCase();
```

Example Code

```
interface DataObjectA {
  source: "dataObjectA";
  data: string;
}

interface DataObjectB {
  source: "dataObjectB";
  data: number;
}


type DOTypes = DataObjectA | DataObjectB
type DOSources = DOTypes["source"];

async function getData(source: DOSources) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://some-random-endpoint/`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  switch (source) {
    case "dataObjectA":
      return await response.json() as DataObjectA;
    case "dataObjectB":
      return await response.json() as DataObjectB;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed get the compiler to compute the desired return type of `getData()` as a function of the `DOTypes` discriminated union and the type of the `source` parameter.  You can make `getData()` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) whose type parameter `K extends DOSources` is the type of the `source` parameter.  For example:

```
async function getData<K extends DOSources>(source: K) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://some-random-endpoint/`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  return await response.json() as Extract<DOTypes, { source: K }>
}
```

To find the member of the `DOTypes` discriminated union associated with `K`, we can use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  `Extract<DOTypes, {source: K}>` selects from `DOTypes` all union members whose `source` property is of a type assignable to `K`.

Note that we have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the function returns a value of (a `Promise` corresponding to) this type; the compiler is unable to verify that.

---

Let's test it:

```
const resultA = await getData("dataObjectA"); // const result: DataObjectA
resultA.data.toLowerCase();

const resultB = await getData("dataObjectB"); // const result: DataObjectB
resultB.data.toFixed();
```

Looks good.  Each result is narrowed to the expected type.  You'll only get a union out of `getData()` if you put a union in:

```
const resultAOrB = await getData(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "dataObjectA" : "dataObjectB");
// const resultAOrB: DataObjectA | DataObjectB
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA8gIwFYQJgCCyA3gFDLIDOA9gK5RIBcyARACYbb6EnsA3FWTdMbGmCigA5sIC+FCqEixEKdJlwEiAIXIj6TVhzG8dYXUJFm2IBgFsc0BUopgAngAcNWACreEDTIALxoPNr8pAA+4Vp8eu6BaFgAyozMQaEpAT40ANrsRpnsALrCFHA0HiAIyDAMtWDAdCDIMhBgmnAAPADSyBAAHpAgnMGoaRlINAB8ABTFJn0AlAbUCK2SyFBBXlsoYXAA7nDAYPWdCAAW8wAG12BgXjQsAPRv9A4QALRQcGM6A4fhAxvsVG87gAadbUZDfMDXOicNjsADiAFE-OwoSJqNcIHBONBXrC4RwAMKtUZgH65CDsVFwLxeAA2wAQGBaIDeeHoIBxeOQ8lx1HkKwq1F2YCYbROZwuuxo+xANAgADo+a15msqsgMSN-kQepN6TQYWRaNMIGwBvJZhRFEoPvqhj4iBBOMhnNc4AA3FpQJRVGp1BpNbn1HUGESbVWKoIMVkkbLy87tTrdeZcCIJAQS5AuuPbJVJsBsbqRIjEESl5PEdVmdVgOgAGTox2gFKqEB1kuQxYTNDL+iOp3THS6PGzZirlnYBaLWyHZYruYsulrieTukbPGbdAAYsAhp6+0oNsudtuSFgoKPkGmLpOswBZDDXdX-QEOaM9ZAAAzqgArMgAD8pjrlE7DIKis55lYEoiEu8bXsO9Z3roa7xBYMRxOY-Cbo6QA)

Comment: Thanks! Very clean approach here.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use *function overloads* to specify the different potential return values for different input types. [Here is a sandbox link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA8gIwFYQJgCCyA3gLABQyyAzgPYCuUSAXMgEQAmG2+hEpwDc1Wr0wc6YKKADmoqgF9q1UJFiIU6TLgJEAQuTH1mrCBx589ggyJMS4HEEwC2OaIpVVqYAJ4ADtpYACqBEHTIALxo1gJEpAA+sbrxYAa+4WhYAMpmSJExqKHhdADanIwsSJwAuorUcHR+IAjIMEytYMAMIMhyEGA6cAAUVeYcwzYJFeM1tQCUHAAKUAyuwHQQADxTacQAfIpNLW0dXT19A0N8Y-kWKfz66bP3dUvIq+ubO3vPBkdGs1Wu1OkRLv1BsM7tUHsU8rC6AtjDRkAhetJkFAIgEMSgYnAAO5wYBgdqDBAACxGAANKWAwAE6GwAPQsxiuCAAWigcBA3HWXIg-Nx6hZNIANCjaLROWBKQxuJYAOIAURCnAlJlolIgcG40GZ0pltE4AGFepBwFywkFOJY4AEAgAbYAIDCXFl4RggTXa5BKLWopQLBqo7FgFh9IkksnYui4kBbAB03t6I1D1G8QNOoIuvWQkGkGeNtDZ9Bk8n96KTcYiTGdZIJxNJkJumBGVlSz2InEzqNo8YbYGTjmTYAYABkGIToGamhAM4oTeWXO5oNWMXW6MOAEzRZAx1vXaFdp62PvLmVDxu70d8ccMABiwAAHhBuCMAMz97xAA) for the following code.

```js
interface DataObjectA {
  source: "dataObjectA";
  data: string;
}

interface DataObjectB {
  source: "dataObjectB";
  data: number;
}

type DOTypes = DataObjectA | DataObjectB
type DOSources = DOTypes["source"];

async function getData(source: DataObjectA["source"]): Promise<DataObjectA>;
async function getData(source: DataObjectB["source"]): Promise<DataObjectB>;
async function getData(source: DOSources) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://some-random-endpoint/`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  return await response.json();
}

async function test() {
    // string
    const result = await getData("dataObjectA");
    result.data.toLowerCase();
    // number
    const result2 = await getData("dataObjectB");
    result2.data.toFixed(3);
}
```

That being said, if you're not actually using the `source` parameter, you could just explicitly pass the type to determine the output rather than passing a variable. Again, [a playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA8gIwFYQJgCCyA3gLABQyyAzgPYCuUSAXMgEQAmG2+hEpwDc1Wr0wc6YKKADmoqgF9q1UJFiIU6TLgJEAQuTH1mrCBx589ggyJMS4HEEwC2OaIpVVqYAJ4ADtpYACqBEHTIALxo1gJEpAA+sbrxYAaK-kFoWADKZkiRMaih4XQA2pyMLEicALqK1HB0fiAIyDBMbWDADCDIchBgOnAAPCHIEAAekCDckSX5NREAfAAUAJQcAApQDK7AdBCjJhPTs-Mp-PokldXm9cgA-Fc2CcgcI2-p1CvGNMgEH1pMgoBEAsCUDE4AB3ODAMAdIYIAAWawABiiwGAAnQ2AB6fGMVwQAC0UDgc32pIgcwh6nx6IANP9aLQSWAUQxuJYAOIAURCnCZJloKIgcG40DxrLZtE4AGE+rMwKSwkFOJY4AEAgAbYAIDC9ED4vCMEDC0XIJQigFKDaNAFgsAsfqw+GIsF0CEgI4AOjNfU2XlUVGarXanW6xuQkGkm1lhPoMnkJiBvs9ESYusR0LhCIGQxGoysqRuxE46wdJi92bAfscfrADAAMgwYdAFc0IMGTEmXO5oGngZm6HWAEzRZDuguDYZ8EuOb52KuKWi1nPjht8JsMABiwCmEG4awAzNXlEA) for this option.

```js
interface DataObjectA {
  source: "dataObjectA";
  data: string;
}

interface DataObjectB {
  source: "dataObjectB";
  data: number;
}

type DOTypes = DataObjectA | DataObjectB;
type DOSources = DOTypes["source"];

async function getData<T extends DOSources>(): Promise<
  T extends DataObjectA["source"] ? DataObjectA : DataObjectB
> {
  const response = await fetch(`https://some-random-endpoint/`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  return await response.json();
}

async function test() {
  // string
  const result = await getData<"dataObjectA">();
  result.data.toLowerCase();
  // number
  const result2 = await getData<"dataObjectB">();
  result2.data.toFixed(3);
}
```